# ID ends with and appendchild / jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey i have problem with my code - can you look and solve my little problem?
I know that $ (   ) is not a function.
i can use getelementbyID but i need function ID ends with

```html
<html>
<head>
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="pane_mrp:mrp">
    asdsad
    </div>    
    
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mrp = document.getElementById('pane_mrp:mrp');
    var ppostaci = document.createElement('div');
    ppostaci.id = ppostaci;
        var newHTML = "<div> bla bla bla</div>"; 
        ppostaci.innerHTML = newHTML;
        $("[id*='mrp']").appendChild(ppostaci);
</script>
```

Comment: Ends with what? `mrp`?

Comment: Why not just used `$('#mrp')`?

Comment: @Robusto Because the element doesn't have an id of just `"mrp"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("[id*='mrp']")[0]` to get the normal JavaScript node element which works with `.appendChild()`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="pane_mrp:mrp">
    asdsad
    </div>    
    
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mrp = document.getElementById('pane_mrp:mrp');
    var ppostaci = document.createElement('div');
    ppostaci.id = ppostaci;
        var newHTML = "<div> bla bla bla</div>"; 
        ppostaci.innerHTML = newHTML;
        $("[id$='mrp']")[0].appendChild(ppostaci);
</script>
```

Note that [`$=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) is the ends-with selector.

You can also use the jQuery function [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$("[id$='mrp']").append(ppostaci)
```

Comment: Or in jQuery just use `.append(ppostaci)`

Comment: @4castle Thanks, I've added that as well.

Answer (score 0):

HI I think AppendChild is not a Jquery Function, have you tried to just run Append?

:)

```html
<html>
<head>
    

</head>
<body>
<div id="pane_mrp:mrp">
    asdsad
    </div>    
    
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mrp = document.getElementById('pane_mrp:mrp');
    var ppostaci = document.createElement('div');
    ppostaci.id = ppostaci;
        var newHTML = "<div> bla bla bla</div>"; 
        ppostaci.innerHTML = newHTML;
        $("[id*='mrp']").append(ppostaci);
</script>
```